# How can I be successful as a digital nomad?

Tags: remote, working-from-home

I have been reading articles on digital nomad-ing.

Here are some of them:

[Being a digital nomad in Bali](http://biz30.timedoctor.com/my-experience-using-time-doctor-to-be-a-digital-nomad-in-bali/)

[This guy built his business by the beach](http://yongfook.com/1-year-as-a-digital-nomad-how-to-build-a-business-by-the-beach.html)

[Joel Gascoigne of Buffer (11 cities in 3 months)](http://joel.is/11-cities-in-3-months-the-highs-and-lows-of-digital-nomad-lifestyle/)

I am a remote worker myself. My 'office' is my laptop. But, I have never really tried living the life of a digital nomad where I stay and live in a different place for extended periods of time.

How can I be successful as a digital nomad?

Comment: You could join programs like Super Nomad Friend Squad. It eases you into this new lifestyle, so you wont get lost or lonely while becoming a digital nomad. You’ll get to live in 4 or 12 cities in a year with a group of like minded people, therefore helping you find what remote jobs you could do to earn money.

Answer (score 26):

I am currently in the process of becoming a digital nomad myself. I have been investigating this for a few months now.

---

#### You must sort out a few things

- **Earn money**: Ideally, you want several income streams to reduce risks.
- **Legal status**: you want to make sure this is sorted out as without that you probably will have trouble charging anyone for your services.
- **Legal address**: you will still have mails coming from organizations & you will need a good system to make this work. Either get a friend or relative to help you, or get a professional service (i.e. in Switzerland the post can scan your mails & email them to you).
- **Banking**: you must have an excellent bank providing cutting edge online services. Forget about old fashion banks & switch to something reliable at anytime from anywhere.
- **Health insurance**: you **must** have a good international health insurance, you'd easily find yourself in big trouble if you have any health issue. see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/776/long-term-travel-what-insurances-can-should-i-get
- **Gear**: you must make sure you have the right tool for the job, once you are away it can be difficult to buy it. Some inspiration on http://www.grownupplayground.com/travel-gear-backpackers-long-term-travelers/
- **Insure your gear**: you want to insure your belongings, it won't save your work but at least it'll reduce the financial impact of getting something stolen.
- **Protect your gear**: uglify your gear so it's less likely to get stolen & buy appropriate housing (shockproof, waterproof, & so on) to prevent physical damage.
- **Protect your data: encrypt sensitive files**: use tools such as Truecrypt or BitLocker to only allow yourself to access your sensitive data.
- **Protect your data: digital backups**: you will probably want to have digital backups of your work. You want a strategy that works smoothly so that if you loose your work (ie. lose your computer in a sailing accident), you can not only access all the lost work but also setup the new gear as the original one in a minimum amount of time.
- **Work place**: you might want to make your life easy & start by moving to a location that is known for welcoming digital nomads, it'll save you tone of time & you'll be able to learn from others
- **Store what you can't take**: you want to have a safe place to store valuable things you can't travel with (i.e. paperwork & electronics). For instance, [Shurgard self-storage in Berlin](http://www.shurgard.de/en/) has containers starting from 1m cube (this one costs 30€/month): it's very safe, has 6am to 10pm access, it's temperature+humidity controlled (no damage even storing for 1+ year) and your belonging are even insured. Put all the things you really care about in such space and then store all the rest in a less safe/expensive place (i.e. in a friend's basement). Regarding access: even if you need something from this storage while on the other side of the globe, all the access is through combination locks, so you can send a trusted person to get whatever is needed (no need for signature or else).
- **Car or Van**: rent, rent, rent! With services such as [Drivy](http://drivy.com/) and many apps for car rentals by the minute, there are only very specific cases that can justify owning a car. Owning a car or converted van sounds ideal to travel around a continent (i.e. Europe), however it is a big administrative burden and a rather high cost. This involves: dealing with insurances (regular & breakdown), yearly car check (MOT, TÜV, or whatever the name: it is at a given deadline in a given country), occasional repairs, occasional accidents, occasional police fines, storage when traveling without it & so on. It will cost you a lot of time, money, and might force you to be in a given place at a given time (for admin reasons): so think twice.
- **Voting**: `"Brexit, Trump, what's next!??"` You will be away from your country and who knows for how long. But you still want your voice to be heard. Setup a way for you to be able to vote (i.e. power of attorney). Some countries are terrible at this (very slow setup), so prepare that well in advance.

---

#### Further resources to get started on being a digital nomad

- https://nomadforum.io/t/digital-nomad-101-how-to-become-a-digital-nomad/465
- http://flagtheory.com/digital-nomad/
- https://nomadforum.io - Biggest Digital Nomad forum
- http://github.com/lukasz-madon/awesome-remote-job#job-boards - Find remote jobs
- https://github.com/kaizensoze/remote-freelance-jobs - Find remote jobs
- http://digitalnomadhub.net
- http://www.nomadicnotes.com/digital-nomad
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_nomad
- http://www.reddit.com/r/digitalnomad
- http://www.nomadicnotes.com/digital-nomad
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_traveler
- When must you pay income taxes? http://www.liferemotely.com/work-while-traveling/managing-a-business/65-paying-taxes-in-your-home-country-when-you-arent-living-there
- http://leapin.eu Estonian e-residency made easy
- https://e-estonia.com Estonian e-residency
- http://e-estonia.com/e-residents/services-and-benefits - Estonian e-residency: Register a company, open a bank account & more
- http://passports.io
- https://freedomsurfer.com/offshore-jurisdictions
- https://nomadforum.io/t/where-should-i-register-my-company-as-a-digital-nomad-singapore-hong-kong/520/4
- https://nomadforum.io/t/is-panama-a-good-destination-for-tax-residency-for-digital-nomads/2588/14
- https://boldanddetermined.com/hong-kong-business-guide/
- http://toomanyadapters.com - tech tips
- https://nomadlist.com/guides - books
- http://toomanyadapters.com/hammocks-hard-drives/ - books
- international health insurance - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/776/long-term-travel-what-insurances-can-should-i-get/46751#46751
- international health insurance - https://nomadforum.io/t/does-international-health-insurance-for-digital-nomads-exist/378
- http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/09/top-10-tactics-for-protecting-your-stuff/
- https://truecrypt.ch
- https://medium.com/nomad-gate/the-world-s-best-bank-accounts-for-international-travelers-and-nomads-3257e6839cff
- http://www.grownupplayground.com/banking-solutions-for-travelers-digital-nomads/
- https://safetywingcom.medium.com/remotely-from-georgia-program-everything-you-need-to-know-34c678fc5635

Good luck

Comment: Hey Adrien. Is it possible to summarize some of the points in the links? What we are ideally looking for is the answer to the question to be hosted *here*, on this site.  If the links were to break, your answer will be useless to future visitors with the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: @jmort253 I'd like to but I do not have the time for this. The amount of information in the provided resources is too big to be summarized. I'll try add a few points that can help the OP to get started however.

Comment: I think that would suffice to include a brief summary, perhaps a paragraph or two. Thanks for putting the time in to collect these resources. It is a fascinating topic.

Comment: done. I hope it's enough. I think that'll be some good guidelines for people getting started with this

Comment: Hey Adrien, this is absolutely fantastic. Thanks for sharing these resources and for briefly summarizing them into points. Should be of great help.

Comment: @AdrienBe, So when you talk about "old fashion banks", what are some examples of "new fashioned banks"?

Comment: @Pacerier by new fashion I mean bank providing excellent remote services (website, app, phone support, email support & more), in France you have Boursorama for instance. Old fashion are the banks providing poor remote services, a bad website (expensive & hard to use), no app, poor phone support, and so on.